# wpa_supplicant wlan debug RaLink RT2760

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, wpa2-psk, wpa-supplicant

I'm attempting to use a `RaLink RT2760 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R Cardbus`. This card auto-configures beautifully under Ubuntu 11.04, but I have a need for 10.04 LTS server, so I'm re-imaging.

*I configure ethernet cards in 10.04 on a regular basis for work, but have never tried wifi. Here's hoping that this is a simple case of a forgotten step.*

```
$ iwconfig
wlan0 RT2860 Wireless  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT2860STA"
      Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
      Bit Rate: 1 Mb/s
      RTS thr:off    Fragment thr:off
      Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:-87 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc: 0  Missed beacon:0
```

I'm assuming by the above that the driver is doing its job correctly.

Now for `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.199
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-ssid MY_SSID
    wpa-ap-scan 1
    wpa-proto RSN
    wpa-pairwise CCMP
    wpa-group CCMP
    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
    psk hashed_password
```

Then I try to start it

```
$ sudo ifup wlan0
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process PID
```

Any assistance much appreciated.

#### Edit 1

```
$ iwlist scan
wlan0    No scan results
```

This seems bad. The network is most definitely up and discoverable.

#### Edit 2

It looks like the boot cd installed me the rt2860 driver. According to [a really old reference post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318539) on the forums, the RTxxx drivers may not be compatible with WPA2. I say *may* because I cannot find any up to date information on this issue. My network is secured WPA2-PSK AES.

Answer (score -1):

```
niemi@hoho:~# lsmod |grep ath
ath5k                 141357  0 
ath                    26067  1 ath5k
mac80211              474202  1 ath5k
cfg80211              405538  3 ath,ath5k,mac80211

---------------------------------------
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    wpa-driver nl80211
    wpa-iface wlan0
    wpa-channel 3
    wpa-ssid "YourWiFiNet"
    wpa-bssid D4:CA:6D:16:F2:F8
    wpa-psk "s7k11l08"
    address 192.168.0.23
    network 192.168.0.0
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers ISPns1 ISPns2
```

---

Comment: What does this mean?